# Cross Platform mobile Chat

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform, chat

I want to develop simple chat application on android as well as IOS, I am using native languages to develop the app.

The same application will be launched on both platforms and I want to make sure the android guy can chat with ios and vice versa.

Comment: You can use phonegap for this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called **Unified Communications as a Service**. There are bunch of cloud providers that provide API, SDK and docs for integration.

Usually it's a single back-end platform with ready APIs and SDKs for various platforms, usually for iOS, Android and Web. But other platform can be supported as well.

I used [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) in many of my applications. They support Messaging, Video Calling and Push Notifications functionality for iOS, Android and Web.

- iOS messaging (chat) guide https://developers.connectycube.com/ios/messaging
- Android messaging (chat) guide https://developers.connectycube.com/android/messaging
- Javascript messaging (chat) guide https://developers.connectycube.com/js/messaging

Chat and Messaging features supported:

- 1-1 messaging
- Group messaging
- Cross-platform
- Sent/Delivered/Read statuses
- ‘Is typing’ statuses
- File attachments
- Automatic push notifications to offline users
- Contact list
- Black list

The whole list of [supported features](https://connectycube.com/features/)

Answer (score 3):

For compatibility between iOS and android, keep In mind following :

Set up same application (server side, top hierarchy) the key used should be common!

APNs of iOS and GCM of Android are supposed to work on the application tokens generated from devices Registered first time and sent to server application  at the same application key, this allow both to stay at same platform and communication.

All play is of server side implementation, handling and reverting back in proper format to iOS and Android.

For more examplification of concept you can check out this applozic.com and their android and iOS GitHub repos for extensive details.
https://github.com/AppLozic

Answer (score 0):

Look also at [apiomat.com](http://www.apiomat.com). They offer a "push module" and a "chat module". If you combine them both, you have a good chat client. There are SDKs for iOS, Java and Android.